# update mysql_query form cookie

Tags: php, mysql

I think this should work in theory. Will it?

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET credtis = credits+1 WHERE id=echo .($_COOKIE['credits_id']!='');";
if ( !($result = $db->sql_query($sql)) )  {
  message_die(GENERAL_ERROR, 'Could not update users table', '', __LINE__, __FILE__, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax was bad for a number of reasons. Try it like this:

```
$id = (!empty($_COOKIE['credits_id']) ? (int) $_COOKIE['credits_id'] : 0;
$sql = "UPDATE users SET credtis = credits+1 WHERE id={$id}";
if (!($result = $db->sql_query($sql))) {
    message_die(GENERAL_ERROR, 'Could not update users table', '', __LINE__, __FILE__, $sql);
}
```

Also, I'm assuming `message_die()` is a part of some framework or API you're using or a custom function of yours. Otherwise, the correct function is `die()` and it would not accept all of those parameters.

Comment: link:
`www.site.com/affiliate/?id=50`

make cookie:
`$credits_id = '$_GET["id"];';
setcookie('credits_id',$credits_id,time() + (3600 * 0.5)); // 3600 = 1 hour`

update db:
`$query = "UPDATE users SET credits+credits-1 WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['credits_id'])."'";`

Comment: Remove the unnecessary (and in fact, incorrect use of) the quotes around `$_GET`.  Change to: `$credits_id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: `setcookie('credits_id',$_GET['id'],time() + (3600 * 0.5)); // 3600 = 1 hour ` bit of clean code

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is bad :P
I corrected it:
`$sql = "UPDATE users SET credits += 1 WHERE id='" . (isset($_COOKIE['credits_id']) && !empty($_COOKIE['credits_id']) ? $_COOKIE['credits_id'] : 0) . "'";`
Here is a more simple version:
`$credits_id = 0;

if (isset($_COOKIE['credits_id']) && !empty($_COOKIE['credits_id']))

$credits_id = (int) $_COOKIE['credits_id'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET credits += 1 WHERE id='" . $credits_id . "'";`
Looking at the != part, do you want to return a value when the cookie isn't set?

PS:
According to "hoi", are you Dutch?

Comment: yes i am dutch dank voor de info